# Handle drag gesture entering composeable bounds

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a (non-lazy) column of text buttons (say, they contain the letters A-Z). I have on-click modifiers applied on each of these buttons that perform an action corresponding to the button clicked. I would like to perform these same actions when the user drags their finger across buttons. That is, if the user presses A and then drags their finger down to D (passing through B and C in the process), I would like to trigger the on-click behaviors for A, B, C, and D in order. There is no other "draggable" effect required on these buttons.

I tried logging the series of `MotionEvents` that were triggered via `pointerInteropFilter` when such an action occurred, but only received events on the starting and ending buttons (A & D).